# Is it possible to redirect only the query params of a route not found?

Tags: angular, angular-router

The application will receive a redirect from an authentication provider, but without hash in the url.

I need redirect the params from 
**http://host/?param1=123** to 
**http://host/#/login?param1=123**

How configure routes for this?

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

Comment: If you didn't know, you don't _need_ to use the `HashLocationStrategy`. We switched (back) to [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_pathlocationstrategy) for specifically this reason. It does, however, require server awareness of your routes (so that your BE redirects all your routes to your main Angular index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be done within the route paths?

**Programmatically** I get the params for reference like this:

```
this.parameters = Object.assign({}, this.route.snapshot.parent.queryParams);
```

Now you can redirect with `this.parameters` or build them up within `navigate` `queryParams` argument

```
this.router.navigate(['/profile/3'], { queryParams: { position: pos, 'salary': 'expensive' } }); // add .then(() => {}) for promise
```

**For redirection**

```
this.router.navigate(['login'], { preserveQueryParams: true });
```

**Template HTML routing**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/3']" [queryParams]="{position:'boss', 'salary': 'expensive' }">
```

If you need more, let me know and I will help you.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but I realized that the problem is about HashLocationStrategy.
**host/?param** does not belong to the router object.
In HashLocation i cant get the params in **host/#/?param..** but not in **host/?param..**

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought you'd need to do this programmatically, not from within the router paths. If you can do this in the path routing I'd love to learn it! @Amir's idea would work, if you want to build/maintain a guard for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with current angular route config `redirectTo` functionality.

What you can do is to write a `[CanActivate]` guard, put it on that empty route `''`, and inside of guard redirect user to `/login` preserving query params using `Router` or returning `UrlTree` from guard.

For example, inside of guard it could look like (using `Router`):

```
  ...
  this.router.navigate(['login'], { preserveQueryParams: true });
  ...
```

Hope that helps.